# Redirect celery task to other queue but don't consume it

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I wish to create task which will redirects itself to other queue in case of error. The purpose of this is to store failed task message with all tasks data and for example use CLI to redirect data to proper queue or remove all of them. But the problem is that if I run task on the other queue the tasks is consumed and RabbitMQ doesn't store any data. Is there any way to prevent queue from consuming messages from RabbitMQ?

````py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, arg):
    try:
        ...
    except MaxRetriesExceededError:
        my_task.apply_async([arg], queue='failed_queue')


my_task.apply_async(['arg'], queue='my_queue')```
````

Comment: How do you start your worker ? You could use the flag `-Q` so that the worker listen only to specific queues, excluding 'failed_queue'.

Otherwise, if you only want to push data in a queue, instead of calling the task again, you could define another queue with `kombu` and push whatever needed there, it won't be consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lotram solutions works.
Celery doesn't consume RabbitMQ messages if worker is started with command:
`celery -A proj worker -Q my_queue -X failed_queue`

`-X` argument don't allow worker to consume from specified queue